# Adding Security Keys?

Tags: security, wp-config

I read the paragraph at the codex on [Security Keys](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Security_Keys).

It offers the example -

```
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         't`DK%X:>xy|e-Z(BXb/f(Ur`8#~UzUQG-^_Cs_GHs5U-&Wb?pgn^p8(2@}IcnCa|' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'D&ovlU#|CvJ##uNq}bel+^MFtT&.b9{UvR]g%ixsXhGlRJ7q!h}XWdEC[BOKXssj' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'MGKi8Br(&{H*~&0s;{k0<S(O:+f#WM+q|npJ-+P;RDKT:~jrmgj#/-,[hOBk!ry^' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'FIsAsXJKL5ZlQo)iD-pt??eUbdc{_Cn<4!d~yqz))&B D?AwK%)+)F2aNwI|siOe' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        '7T-!^i!0,w)L#JK@pc2{8XE[DenYI^BVf{L:jvF,hf}zBf883td6D;Vcy8,S)-&G' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'I6`V|mDZq21-J|ihb u^q0F }F_NUcy`l,=obGtq*p#Ybe4a31R,r=|n#=]@]c #' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'w<$4c$Hmd%/*]`Oom>(hdXW|0M=X={we6;Mpvtg+V.o<$|#_}qG(GaVDEsn,~*4i' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'a|#h{c5|P &xWs4IZ20c2&%4!c(/uG}W:mAvy<I44`jAbup]t=]V<`}.py(wTP%%' );
```

and the note

> You don't have to remember the keys, just make them long, random and
>   complicated -- or better yet, use the online generator.

Is it this simple, to add that code (obviously, using their generator to change the text) to the wp-config file?

Comment: You don't even need to add the Security Keys if they already exist. They'll usually be created when WordPress is installed.

Comment: I looked. Not there. Are you saying a new installation would have this, but updates over the years don't?

Comment: As of ~6 years ago WP installs should automatically generate unique salts, see: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12159
I'm not sure if the WP upgrade mechanism would have checked if the salts were there and added them if they were missing.

Comment: Also yes, it's that simple to add that code to the wp-config file. I just tested commenting out then changing my salts and all I had to do was log back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you use the generator to create the salts then add them to your `wp-config.php` file you can start reaping the benefits of much greater security.

Any current sessions will be invalidated so you'll have to log back in but otherwise there shouldn't be any noticeable change.

Automatic generation of random salts was added [a few years back](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12159) so any new WordPress installs should automatically generate their own unique salts.

Comment: Ok. Got it. After earlier comments, I found that newer sites had this, but my older ones didn't. So going through and adding where missing.